# what is exactly firebase.database()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
db=firebase.database()
```

hello guys, I just had a little understanding problem.
can someone please explain to me exactly what all this means individual. I want to understand this....

Comment: That's a singleton which is a programming concept. See [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

It's getting the singleton instance of [Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database) that you can use to query Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: what is singleton :D ?

Comment: can you say this with other words?

Comment: The only instance of Database available.